# PDO : how do I get the result of SELECT FOUND_ROWS()?

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PDO, sorry that this is so simplistic.

Basically, I want to `SELECT` and both get the returned rows and the number of those rows, cheking for zero rows before processing further.

`$rows = $conn->query('SELECT ...)` allows me to `foreach($rows as $row)` but, as I said, I want to check for zero.

`count($rows)` always returns 1, even if there are no results(!).

I thought of using `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` followed by
`$foundRows = $connection->exec('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS numRows');` but I am so dumb that I can't figure out how to get the number of rows from that.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: @AwladLiton `PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by the last **DELETE**, **INSERT**, or **UPDATE** statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

Comment: @djay It also returns the number of rows in a `SELECT` statement for MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Basically, I want to SELECT and both get the returned rows and the number of those rows,

you are selecting rows wrong way

```
 $rows = $conn->query('SELECT ...')->fetchAll();
```

will actually give you $rows array which can be counted. However,

> cheking for zero rows before processing further.

You don't need to count $rows for this. Just use $rows array itself:

```
id (!$rows) ... // no rows returned
```

As of the case where you INDEED need SELECT FOUND_ROWS() - then to get a result from the query, you should **fetch** it:

```
$foundRows = $connection->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn();
```

And remember that you should never use exec with PDO.

Comment: Errm, another dumb question, but ... "remember that you should never use exec with PDO" ?

Comment: exec() doesn't support placeholders in queries while you should always substitute real date with placeholders and thus use prepare/execute.

Comment: OIC. Then how dos that fit in with the answer? I am taking my parameters from an HTTP ET request, so should be using prepared statements.

Comment: it does fit in the answer because you have used exec in your question. Note that you should use placeholders for ANY data, regfrdless of source

Comment: +1 Thanks again. I can't remember what I meant by "how does that fit in.."; it was posted rather late last night. It wasn't meant to be rude, though it reads a little that way when I see it now. I just wish I could remember what I really wanted to ask. Maybe that you said "never use exec..." then "use prepare/execute"? Nvm, not really important, I guess. Thanks again for your help.